# Role of voltage source in relaxation oscillator

Tags: voltage, analog, oscillator

I have found this relaxation oscillator

[image]

Where you can put a ground in the anode of the battery.

The role of the battery is to start the oscillation only or what?

Comment: Did you realize that the diode is a tunnel diode and will sustain oscillation?

Comment: Andy aka the oscillation is due to the negative differential resistance area of the tunnel diode.

Answer (score 2):

You can "thwack" a coil and make it oscillate, but it'll run out of energy.  Nothing is perfect, so energy gets lost with every oscillation cycle.  Because of this lost energy, the coil needs to get "thwacked" periodically so that oscillation will continue.

The battery is there to provide those "thwacks" to start the oscillation, and to make it continue by making up the energy lost in the resistors.

No battery, no oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

The resistors will cause circuit losses, as will any real-world coil.  Those losses have to be continually overcome for the oscillator to continue oscillating -- the battery provides that energy.

Which point to ground is arbitrary -- just pick any wire in the circuit and draw a ground symbol on it.